# how can I debug this android error using my device?

Tags: android, titanium, ddms

I get the following errors in `DDMS`. But how can I trace this to the line that throws this exception? What do you think could be the cause of the following error?

[image]

Is checking the `DDMS` the best way to debug an android application? I am using titanium.

Thank you,

Ryan

Comment: Generally, you can find Caused By:.... in log. in above log it is - Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: Have you ask support in Titanium forum ?

Comment: look lower in the stacktrace print out under where it says "caused by"(you are currently highlighting the top most portion)

Comment: Show us the line(s) that point to your source code. That points to your code... in that whole bunch.

Comment: my code is written in javascript and compiled to java. I can get no useful data from the error besides the cause/ correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application attempt to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that string does not have the appropriate format.

Comment: I believe line 321 refers to the source in `FloatingPointParser` in the Apache Harmony library. He must try to find the line that points to *his* source code I believe.

Comment: @K_Anas can we debug the Titanium javaScript coding ?

Comment: @AndroidCoader see this link https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Debugging+JavaScript

Comment: Can I know which is the line that does that in my JS file in titanium ? Apache Harmony library is maybe used by titanium, but not by me.

Comment: it was because I added dp to border width. It doesn't support that